# Configuring NIC device in Solaris 9 SPARC OS [QEMU]

Tags: networking, dns, solaris, qemu, nic

I have Xubuntu 18.04 installed on my PC.
I have created a 10G .img image file created by QEMU-IMG. I have installed inside of it Solaris 9 SPARC edition [GUI interface].
If I try and mount the image file as a loop device (using sudo losetup /dev/loop0 /path-to-img-file) I can only mount it as read only.
When I type in dmesg into terminal I am informed that the UFS kernel has been compiled in read-only support.
I investigated into this and found that the Linux UFS kernel is compiled to be as such (read only for UFS) as there has been data loss issues when mounting UFS file systems as read,write in the past.
Therefore I need to setup an internet connection within Solaris 9 through the QEMU VM
I know about editing the following configuration files ...

```
/etc/defaultrouter
/etc/nsswitch.conf
/etc/resolv.conf
/etc/hosts
(etc)
```

But what I am struggling to do is locate and/or install the driver for my NIC card on my mounted Solaris 9 OS and activate it (ifconfig XXPUT-NIC-DEV-HEREXXX up)
If I can do that then I can get down to business on the conf files above.
Can anyone help? I shall gladly await your response

regards

Comment: Solaris 9 can read CD/DVDs, so you can create an ISO filesystem with the driver in it, then use QEMU to present that to the Solaris 9 VM.

Comment: Hi andrew. I dont what you mean. Can you give me a more technical explanation if possible?